# Есть ли тут ляп?

Tags: стилистика

На сообществе ["Нарочно не придумаешь"](http://life-humour.diary.ru/) вышел один спор. Предложение было следующее: "При сильном ветре спасатели рекомендуют плотно закрыть окна, не находиться вблизи деревьев, а также парковать рядом с ними автотранспорт". Мне кажется, что тут явный ляп: выходит, будто спасатели рекомендуют парковать машины под деревьями. Другие утверждают, что ляпа нет. А вы как думаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, здесь нужно обязательно во избежание неверного понимания перед вторым инфинитивом использовать НЕ: *"При сильном ветре спасатели рекомендуют плотно закрыть окна, не находиться вблизи деревьев, а также НЕ парковать рядом с ними автотранспорт".* Спасатели рекомендуют (что?) НЕ находиться и НЕ парковать. Нужно порыться в учебниках, но, как мне кажется, частица НЕ должна относиться к одному глаголу, перед которым употребляется, а не к целой группе однородных глаголов. Навскидку пришло в голову: *Чтоб НЕ пил, НЕ курил и цветы всегда дарил*. Попробуйте убрать НЕ перед вторым глаголом. Получится какая-то ерунда: *Чтоб НЕ пил, курил и цветы всегда дарил*. Смысл меняется, не так ли? :-))

Comment: @olsa, это не нуждается ни в каких учебниках. "НЕ" от глагола не отрывается ни при каких обстоятельствах. Не беру умышленные нарушения грамматики. От других частей речи - ещё можно придумывать какие-то отговорки (это было НЕ яблоко или груша), но только не с глаголом. Это одна лексико-грамматическая единица, хоть и пишется раздельно (на то есть исторические причины).

Предвижу возражение: а почему тогда нельзя по анологии с упомянутыми фруктиами "он не ходил или бегал"? Отвечаю. Потому, что как минимум двусмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Ляп явный. И, увы, очень частый. Не знаю, чем он объясняется, потеряно то ли обязательное НЕ (его нельзя отрывать от глаголов), то ли "запрещено", но автор явно не прочитал своё творчество.